# What is this 6-pin SMD IC?

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

[image]

I have Huawei WiFi router which burn due to the change to router power supply. Now I am trying to replace the burnt voltage regulator or chip but I don't have much knowledge to identify the exact component.

Model of router is Huawei Echolife EG8141A5 GPON.

Comment: Given ``U4`` has been damaged such that the case has _exploded_ and obliterated where any device marking would have been, from the picture can't identify the component. Do you have another router of the same model to be able to take a picture of an undamaged ``U4`` to read the device marking?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The resistors to the right look a little ... toasted ... too.

Comment: It's impossible to know what chip this is exactly but the chip is a SOT23-6 form factor. Given that it's next to a large inductor and a large plain, the chip may be providing a voltage rail, perhaps a switching buck converter for a small voltage. I haven't taken apart any Huawei products to know who their preferred suppliers are. Given that it is a Chinese company, I would guess that it could be either Richtek, Silergy, or Leshen Radio Company.

Comment: No i don't have any other router but i can share router details link https://www.maytelecom.com.cn/eg8141a5-huawei-gpon-onu/